# Stuck in UIImageView masking multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on UIImageView masking. Where i want image background like below.

[image]

You can see the black effect at bottom on text "Himalaya Gel".

I want to add such effect every time i add image.

So if anybody know's the solution pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gradient on the UIImageView, any time you change the UIImage, the gradient will still stay.

```
- (void)addGradientToView:(UIView *)view
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height * 0.8, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height * 0.2);
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                        (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

The gradient will only start on the bottom of the view (view.hieght * 0.8) with a clear color, and continue till the end will black gradient.